# "Error cannot post/test" when i'm trying to login with gogle account in angular app

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, google-account

```
<div
    id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="1050792325707-eub73vnvrvsueu3a7otn9lokmd6nv1g1.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-context="use"
    data-ux_mode="redirect"
    data-itp_support="false"
    r
    data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
  ></div>
  <!-- data-auto-select="true" -->
  <div
    class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="pill"
    data-theme="filled_blue"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left"
  ></div>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
type here
```

`handleCredentialResponse(response:any) {
this.loginserve(response).subscribe(s=>{});
}

```
loginserve(x:any):Observable<any>
{

 return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:7213/api/Auth/Token',x.value);
}`
```

[this what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thS8o.png)